# ConcurrentModificationException with LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, concurrentmodification, linkedhashmap

Not sure what is triggering a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` when I iterate over the `LinkedHashMap` structure in the code below. Using the `Map.Entry` approach works fine. Did not get a good explanation on what is triggering this from the previous posts.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LRU {

    // private Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    // private SortedMap<String,Integer> lru_cache = Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<String, Integer>());

    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 3;

    private LinkedHashMap<String,Integer> lru_cache = new LinkedHashMap<String,Integer>(MAX_SIZE, 0.1F, true){
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
            return(lru_cache.size() > MAX_SIZE);
         }
    };    

    public Integer get1(String s){
        return lru_cache.get(s);        
    }

    public void displayMap(){
        /**
         * Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(LinkedHashMap.java:373)
            at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:384)
            at LRU.displayMap(LRU.java:23)
            at LRU.main(LRU.java:47)
         */
        *for(String key : lru_cache.keySet()){
            System.out.println(lru_cache.get(key));
        }*

// This parser works fine        
//        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> kv : lru_cache.entrySet()){
//            System.out.println(kv.getKey() + ":" + kv.getValue());
//        }
    }

    public void set(String s, Integer val){
        if(lru_cache.containsKey(s)){            
            lru_cache.put(s, get1(s) + val);
        }
        else{
            lru_cache.put(s, val);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LRU lru = new LRU();
        lru.set("Di", 1);
        lru.set("Da", 1);
        lru.set("Daa", 1);
        lru.set("Di", 1);        
        lru.set("Di", 1);
        lru.set("Daa", 2);
        lru.set("Doo", 2);
        lru.set("Doo", 1);        
        lru.set("Sa", 2);
        lru.set("Na", 1);
        lru.set("Di", 1);
        lru.set("Daa", 1);

        lru.displayMap();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you really mean to have a load factor of 0.1 as you set the initial capacity to MAX_SIZE.  What the load factor does is ensure there is at least a capacity of size()/load_factor. i.e. when you have 3 keys, you will have a capacity of at least 30 (actually 32 as it has to be a power of 2).  I suggest using `MAX_SIZE*10/7` and the default load factor of `0.7f` which will give you a capacity of 4 in this case.

Answer (score 47):

Read the [Javadoc for `LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings or, in the case of access-ordered linked hash maps,
>   affects iteration order. In insertion-ordered linked hash maps, merely
>   changing the value associated with a key that is already contained in
>   the map is not a structural modification. **In access-ordered linked
>   hash maps, merely querying the map with `get` is a structural
>   modification.**

Since you're passing in `true` to the `LinkedHashMap` constructor, it is in access order and when you are trying to `get` something from it, you are structurally modifying it.

Also note that when you use the enhanced `for` syntax, you are actually using an iterator. Simplified quote from [JLS §14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced `for` statement has the form:
>
> ```
> EnhancedForStatement:
>
> for ( TargetType Identifier : Expression ) Statement
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If the type of *Expression* is a subtype of `Iterable<X>` for some type
>   argument `X`, then let `I` be the type `java.util.Iterator<X>`; otherwise,
>   let `I` be the raw type `java.util.Iterator`.
>
> The enhanced `for` statement is equivalent to a basic `for` statement of
>   the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>      TargetType Identifier =
>          (TargetType) #i.next();
>      Statement
> }
> ```
>
> `#i` is an automatically generated identifier that is distinct from any other identifiers (automatically generated or otherwise) that are in
>   scope (§6.3) at the point where the enhanced for statement occurs.

Also, in the Javadoc for `LinkedHashMap`:

> The iterators returned by the `iterator` method of the collections
>   returned by all of this class's collection view methods are
>   *fail-fast*: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own
>   `remove` method, the iterator will throw a
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Therefore, when you are calling `get` on the map, you are performing structural modifications to it, causing the iterator in the enhanced-for to throw an exception. I think you meant to do this, which avoids calling `get`:

```
for (Integer i : lru_cache.values()) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You're using an access-ordered linked hash map: from the spec at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html,

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings or, in the case of access-ordered linked hash maps,
>   affects iteration order. In insertion-ordered linked hash maps, merely
>   changing the value associated with a key that is already contained in
>   the map is not a structural modification. In access-ordered linked
>   hash maps, merely querying the map with get is a structural
>   modification.)

Simply calling `get` is enough to be considered a structural modification, triggering the exception. If you use the `entrySet()` sequence you're only querying the entry and NOT the map, so you don't trigger the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 6):

In the constructor of `LinkedHashMap` you pass `true` to get the LRU behaviour (meaning the eviction policy is **access order** rather than `false` for **insertion order**).

So every time you call `get(key)` the underlying Map.Entry increments an access counter AND reorders the collection by moving the (last accessed) Map.Entry to the head of the list.

The iterator (implicitly created by the for loop) checks the modified flag, which is different from the copy it took originally, so throws the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

To avoid this you should use the `entrySet()` as the implementation is inherited from java.util.HashMap and therefore the iterator doesn't check the modification flags:

```
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : lru_cache.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(e.getValue());
    }
```

Be aware this class isn't threadsafe so in concurrent environments you will need to use an potentially expensive guards like Collections.synchronizedMap(Map).  In this scenario a better option might be [Google's Guava Cache](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).

Answer (score 3):

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` : If there are any structural changes (additions, removals, rehashing, etc.) to the underlying list while the iterator exists. The iterator checks to see if the list has changed before each operation. This is known as 'failsafe operation'.

If a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.Here you cannot call the `get()` method while using an iterator because calling `get()` structurally modifies the map and hence the next call to one of the iterators method fails and throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
for(String key : lru_cache.keySet()){
    System.out.println(lru_cache.get(key));
}
```

Actually compiles to:

```
Iterator<String> it = lru_cache.keySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String key = it.next();
    System.out.println(lru_cache.get(key));
}
```

Next, your LRU cache shrinks itself to MAX_SIZE elements not when calling `set()`, but when calling `get()` - above answers explain why.

Thus we have following behavior:

- new iterator created to iterate over `lru_cache.keySet()` collection
- `lru_cache.get()` called to extract element from your cache
- `get()` invocation truncates `lru_cache` to MAX_SIZE elements (in your case 3)
- iterator `it` becomes invalid due to collection modification and throws on next iteration.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of fail-fast behaviour of collections framework also when you modify the list (by adding or removing elements) while traversing a list with this error will be there with Iterator. I came across this error some time back . Refer below threads to for detail info.

[ConcurrentModificationException when adding inside a foreach loop in ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806421/concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-arraylist)

Though this says array list, it applies for most of the collection(s) data strucutres.

[Concurrent Modification Exception : adding to an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866238/concurrent-modification-exception-adding-to-an-arraylist)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html