# why concurrent modification on foreach method but not on for loop

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

```
 ArrayList<Integer> targets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 targets.add(2);
 targets.add(2);

 for (Integer testInt : targets )
 {
       targets.add(1);
 }
```

I am getting an concurrentModificationException,But with normal for loop. I am not getting any exception.
in normal forloop like:-

```
for(int i=0;i<target.size();i++)
{
   System.out.println(target.get(i));
   target.add(22); //no exception
   target.remove(2) // no exception 
}
```

Comment: how are serviceQueue and targets related.... i dont see the spot...

Comment: I just edited the question

Comment: If you modify an ArrayList during an enhanced-for-loop the invisible interator behind will throw an exception. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806421/concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-arraylist

The usual for-loop works different, you access the list and its size directly, not via an interator.

Comment: where I can the implementation details of foreach loop. In google Guava, it doesnt show any implementation details. can I see JDK  implementation.

Comment: Check the link which I mentioned in my comment

Comment: @shiv Here is the language specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ForEach loop won't loop directly on your collection. It uses the iterator of your collection behind. you can see the iterator in your collections implementation.

From [Arraylist source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.iterator%28%29)

```
735 
736     public Iterator<E> More ...iterator() {
737         return new Itr();
738     }


An optimized version of AbstractList.Itr
742 
743     private class More ...Itr implements Iterator<E> {
744         int cursor;       // index of next element to return
```

And your foreach loop equals to

```
for(Iterator<Integer> i = targets.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  Integer element = i.next();
  //To do
}
```

So if you doing any operation here, and the same time you modifying the collection,  iterator under the hood got confuse and throws exception.

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2)

```
List<? extends Integer> l = ...
for (float i : l) ...
```

will be translated to:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> #i = l.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
    float #i0 = (Integer)#i.next();
    ...
```

Comment: correct in JLS it is mention, but can we see the source code,

Comment: *iterator under the hood got confuse*... Not really. It's explicitly trying to detect modification.