# How to fix ConcurrentModificationException, removing item from arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to delete an item from my arrayList while iterating through it, and the `ArrayList` has a type class Members. I have read multiple examples of how to fix this problem however none have worked, the `ConcurrentModificationException` is still thrown.

```
Iterator<Members> itr = members.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
  Members foundMember = itr.next();
  if (foundMember.equals(member)){
    itr.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: `members.removeIf(m -> m.equals(member));`  would be an easier way to do this.

Comment: This code would not throw a CME in and of itself: this is the correct way to remove whilst iterating. `members` must be updated elsewhere (or this code is invoked from multiple threads).

Comment: Can you post your entire code!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution i ended up with was, using a CopyOnWriteArrayList, instead of an ArrayList nad using the remove(); methode.

Answer (score -1):

*EDIT* of course my first solution was incorrect *facepalm*
as suggested above, ".removeIf" is most likely the simplest solution.

just use a "normal" for loop (I think that should work, pls. take a look at 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806421/concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-arraylist), btw. an "enhanced for loop" will not work.

```
List<Member> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Member> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list1);
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
  Member member = list1.get(i);
  ...
  list2.remove(member);
}
list1 = list2;
```

Comment: You will skip the member at the next index though