# Java - How to find and remove an element in an ArrayList made of a custom class using one of that classes attributes

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to find and remove an element from my ArrayList `list` (made from a custom master class `ShoppingBasket`) based on a user inputted String `itemSearch` whereby they would enter say `Apple` if they wanted to remove that from the basket, regardless of if the quantity is higher than 1.

The project is setup so that I have a masterclass `ShoppingCart`, with several subclasses `Fruit`, `Dairy`. Each class has a `itemName` and `itemQuantity` attribute.

Here is my `Fruit` class:

```
    public class Fruit extends ShoppingBasket {
        Fruit(String itemName, int itemQuantity){
                super(itemName, itemQuantity);
        } 
    }
```

Here is my `Dairy` sub-class code:

```
    public class Dairy extends ShoppingBasket{
        Dairy(String itemName, int itemQuantity){
            super(itemName, itemQuantity);
        }
    }
```

For my `ShoppingCard` class I have hard-coded examples of instances of the `Fruit` and `Diary` classes and added them to a list to use as test data. I then try to iterate through that list and check each item against the name of the item the user has inputted and when it has found the correct item I try to remove it and print out the result. However, when it goes to print out the result, the program has not removed the item. When Debugging and using a `Stop point` I notice the program does not enter the if statement.

Below is the code for the master `ShoppingBasket` class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboBoxUI.ItemHandler;

public class ShoppingBasket {
    public String itemName;
    public int itemQuantity;

    static String itemSearch;

    ShoppingBasket(String itemName, int itemQuantity){
        this.itemName = itemName;
        this.itemQuantity = itemQuantity;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ShoppingBasket> list = new ArrayList<ShoppingBasket>();

        list.add(new Fruit("Apple", 2));
        list.add(new Fruit("Orange", 4));
        list.add(new Dairy("Semi-Skimmed Milk", 1));
        list.add(new Dairy("Full Fat Milk", 3));

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the item that you want to remove from your basket? ");
        itemSearch = scnr.nextLine();

        for(ShoppingBasket s: list){
            if(s.getItemName() != null && s.getItemName().contains(itemSearch)){
                list.remove(itemSearch);
            }
           
         }

        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Item name: " + this.itemName + " | Quantity: " + this.itemQuantity;
    }
    public String getItemName(){
        return itemName;
    }
}
```

Any help or hints of where I am going wrong would be appreciated. I apologise if this code is messy, I am new and trying to grasp the basics like `Super Class` and `Sub Classes` as well as other concepts of Java.

Comment: Have you tried using a normal for loop instead of an enhanced for loop when removing the item? Enhanced for loops are not to be used when adding or removing items to the list.

Comment: You are trying to remove String that you've read with scanner instead of actual item. In line `list.remove(itemSearch)` replace `itemSearch` with `s`. Also as @AdrianRusso wrote you shouldn't use foreach loop to change list. Look here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806421/concurrentmodificationexception-when-adding-inside-a-foreach-loop-in-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to remove instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i).getItemName() != null && list.get(i).getItemName().contains(itemSearch)) {
        list.remove(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The clear mistake on your code was the line below:

```
list.remove(itemSearch);
```

You used the `itemSearch` String variable to remove the element from the list which was wrong. You should supply the **element** you want to delete to the *remove* method.

**SOLUTION**

To fix it you can simply replace the line mentioned above with:

```
list.remove(s);
```

In **java 8** or above you can try the solution below with java streams:

```
List<ShoppingBasket> filteredList = list.stream()
    .filter(shoppingBasket -> shoppingBasket.getName() != null && !shoppingBasket.getItemName().containsIgnoreCase(itemSearch))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It is recommended not to use `remove()` in an enhanced for-loop. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java).

Comment: noted on this, will update answer for future references