# Threads and Concurrent Modification Exception working with a list

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, concurrency

I know this is a daft questions but cant work out how to fix this, I have not had much experience with using threads before.

Below should create first of all a timer which will execute the command output.write(mylist) every 10 seconds which will simply output the contents of mylist.

Secondly it loops through about 3 lists I have and for each them creates a thread which will continue to loop through getting the next word in the list.
Please note: this is stripped down version and not complete so please don't comment on the arraylist / list but rather the error itself.

There is a concurrent modification exception happening frequently but not all the time when it tries to do `output.write()`.  I am guessing this is because one of the other threads are currently saving something to `mylist`? How would I go about fixing this?

```
    Runnable timer = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    output.write(mylist);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
        }
    };
    Thread timerThread = new Thread(timer);
    timerThread.start();

    for (final ValueList item : list) {

        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {

                        char curr = item.getNext();

                         mylist.addWord(curr);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {}
            }
        };

        Thread thr = new Thread(r);
        thr.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `output.write(mylist);` do? I think you're missing synchronization steps over there. Consider posting relevant part of your code, if not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) highlighting your issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> There is a concurrent modification exception happening frequently but not all the time when it tries to do `output.write`...

The problem is (I assume) that the `output.write(...)` method is iterating through your `myList` at the same time as another thread is calling `myList.addWord(curr);`.  This is not allowed unless `myList` is a concurrent collection.

> How would I go about fixing this?

You will need to synchronize on `myList` every time you are accessing it -- in this case when you are outputting it or adding a word to it.

```
  synchronized (myList) {
      output.write(mylist);
  }
  ...

  synchronized (myList) {
      myList.addWord(curr);
 }
```

In this case, because `output.write(mylist)` is probably iterating through the list, you cannot use the `Collections.synchronizedList(...)` method because the iterators need to be synchronized by the caller.

If this is some high-performance method that is called tons of times then you could also use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` but that is a queue, not a list obviously.  `ConcurrentSkipList` is another option although that is a heavier data structure.

Comment: I agree with the solution, well explained.

Comment: -1 **NOT TRUE:** "You could also define myList as a synchronized list in which case the Collections wrapper class will take care of the synchronization for you." See https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java, search for "Must be manually synched by user!", see also the bottom end of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38199451/3500521 about compound operations.

Comment: You are exactly right @DreamspacePresident.  I missed the implied iterator there.  Thanks!

Comment: :) Removed the -1, which weirdly was possible still, probably because of your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said, this is happening because Java iterators are fail-fast, and will fail if the collection is concurrently modified.
One easy solution is to protect accesses to your list with `synchronized`, but this will cause your threads to stop, waiting for the output to complete.

One maybe smarter solution is to use some concurrent implementation of List.
Since your list is often modified, `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not the solution you want.
If it doesn't require too many modifications, you might use a `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` or a `LinkedBlockingDeque`, which are backed by a linked list, and do **not** implement `List`, so they don't have a `get` method (which you don't seem to be using). Anyway, the iterators returned by these collections are not fail-fast, but weakly-consistent (which means they will 'see' the collection how it was when the iterator was created, or reflect some of the later modifications).

Another solution may be to use a concurrent collection (`ConcurrentLinkedDeque`) and a ReadWriteLock, but in a more original way. Your writer threads would use the read lock (thus being able to write concurrently). You printer thread would acquire the write lock (thus temporarily blocking the other threads), make a copy of the collection into a non-concurrent collection, release the write lock and finally print its local copy.

A definitely smarter (and probably faster) choice would be to assign a different non-concurrent list to each thread. So you would have a list of non-concurrent lists, each assigned to a single thread. When all the threads are done, you can join all your lists into a single one. Moreover, each of the lists should be protected by a lock. When your printer thread wants to print, it iterates through the lists, locking them one at a time, making a copy of it, releasing the lock, and then printing it.

The reason why I insist in making copies is that it's faster, much faster than printing I/O. If your worker threads will have to wait for the printer thread to print the list, all your computation will slow down.

PS: even if the only wrong thing you can see is the exception, `ArrayList`s are not thread safe. If you add elements to the same list from multiple threads, you will lose some elements (unless some weirder exception occurs).

Answer (score 0):

Or just add `synchronized` to the deceleration of `run()`. Alternatively enclose the contents of the method in a `synchronized{...}` block, as long as the sleeping/waiting is in the 'synchronized zone', i.e. where only one thread is allowed to operate at a time.

Anyone reading this for something they're stuck on shoud read through:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html
It will be sound investment in time;)