# LinkedList checkForComodification error java

Tags: java, linked-list, concurrentmodification

Ok so what I am trying to do here is to have a method "running" a process for a given amount of "time" this all seams to work to a degree but it keeps giveing these eceptions.
This is the first execption it gives

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

and then later on in the exicutio it gives this

```
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:761)
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:696)
at parta.PartA.runQueueOne(PartA.java:273)
```

I dont know what I am doing  wrong here am i supposed make this concurrent or something? If so how? I thought that linked list were synchronous by nature? maybe that where im getting this messed up.

Well any way here is the method that im usings:

```
public static void runQueueOne(LinkedList<MyProcess> q1, LinkedList<MyProcess> q2, LinkedList<MyProcess> q3, LinkedList<MyProcess> q4, int ct) {
    System.out.println("Running Level One Queue");


    for (MyProcess p : q1) {
        if (p.name.equalsIgnoreCase(q1.getFirst().name)) {
            //add 3 millsedonds to the service time
            q1.getFirst().serviceTimeTotal += 3;
            System.out.println(q1.getFirst().name + " is running");

        } else {
            //add 3 millseconds to wait time fr the un busy one
            p.waitTimeTotal += 3;
        }
    }

    for (MyProcess p : q2) {
        p.waitTimeTotal += 3;
    }
    for (MyProcess p : q3) {
        p.waitTimeTotal += 3;
    }
    for (MyProcess p : q4) {
        p.waitTimeTotal += 3;
    }

    //calculate all the priority
    for (MyProcess p : q1) {
        p.calculatePriority();
        switch (p.priority) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                q1.remove(p);
                q2.add(p);
                break;
            case 3:
                q1.remove(p);
                q3.add(p);
                break;
            case 4:
                q1.remove(p);
                q4.add(p);
                break;
        }

    }
    ct += 3;
}
```

and here is where I call it in the main method

```
while (!allProcessDone) {
    //arrival queue
    for (MyProcess p : al) {
        addToQueue(qOne, p, currentTime);

        //cheack to see if all the processes are done
        if (p1.isDone == true &
                p2.isDone == true &
                p3.isDone == true &
                p4.isDone == true &
                p5.isDone == true &
                p6.isDone == true &
                p7.isDone == true &
                p8.isDone == true &
                p9.isDone == true &
                p10.isDone == true) {
            //end the loop
            allProcessDone = true;
            System.out.println("All proccess have been completed");
            break;
        }


        switch (robin) {
            case 1:
                runQueueOne(qOne, qTwo, qThree, qFour, currentTime);
                robin = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                runQueueTwo(qOne, qTwo, qThree, qFour, currentTime);
                robin = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                runQueueThree(qOne, qTwo, qThree, qFour, currentTime);
                robin = 4;
                break;
            case 4:
                runQueueFour(qOne, qTwo, qThree, qFour, currentTime);
                robin = 1;
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I would use an ExecutorService which is built-in, thread safe, combines a Queue and a Thread Pool and allows you to obtain the results of individual tasks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are Concurrently accessing and modifying the Collection, that can't be done from for-each loop directly.

You have to use `Iterator` to solve this problem.

```
LinkedList<MyProcess> q1 = new LinkedList<MyProcess>();

Iterator<MyProcess> iterator = q1.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()){
     MyProcess mp = iterator.next();

     if (mp.name.equals("xyz")){
         iterator.remove();    // You can do the modification here.
     }
 }
```

Comment: well I like this approach and I tried it but it still gives me the same errors   `Iterator<MyProcess> it = q1.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            MyProcess mp = it.next();
            mp.calculatePriority();
            switch(mp.priority)
             {
                 case 1: break;
                 case 2: q1.remove(mp); q2.add(mp); break;
                 case 3: q1.remove(mp); q3.add(mp); break;
                 case 4: q1.remove(mp); q4.add(mp); break;
             }
        } `

Comment: Scratch that i got it to work I was not using the itorator.remove() function I was using the linked list one

Comment: @MNM I am glad that you did it, and you are most Welcome

Answer (score 3):

ConcurrentModificationException occurs when you try to remove an element from a List while you are iterating through it using a for loop.

I'm guessing your error is coming from these lines:

```
for (MyProcess p : q1) {
    p.calculatePriority();

    switch (p.priority) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            q1.remove(p);
            q2.add(p);
            break;
        case 3:
            q1.remove(p);
            q3.add(p);
            break;
        case 4:
            q1.remove(p);
            q4.add(p);
            break;
    }
}
```

To fix the error, use [iterator.remove()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-java-iterator-next) method