# ConcurrentModificationException on Iterator.next()

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting a ConcurrentModificationException on the following code:

```
private static List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();
...
public void doTasks(){
    synchronized(tasks){
        Iterator<Task> it = tasks.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            Task t = it.next(); < Exception is always thrown on this line.

            if(t.isDone()){
                it.remove();
            } else {
                t.run();
            }
        }
    }
}
...
public void addTask(Task t){
    synchronized(tasks){
        tasks.add(t);
    }
}
...
public void clearTasks(){
    synchronized(tasks){
        tasks.clear();
    }
}
```

The Object "tasks" is not used anywhere else in the class. I'm not sure why I'm getting the exception. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which line is the exception on?

Comment: I would use an ExecutorService.  You can submit tasks to it and it is built in.

Comment: I added that information regarding where the exception is thrown into the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
if(t.isDone()){
    ...
} else {
    t.run(); // probably changing the task, so consequently the list tasks
}
```

EDIT: you can't change the `tasks` list in the loop. Check out the [`ConcurrentModificationException` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) for more details.

Cheers!

Comment: I read elsewhere that you can if you use Iterator.remove(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-java-iterator-next

Comment: @idunnololz yup, you're absolutely right. `remove` is an optional operation so it can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`, otherwise it's supported by the underlying `Collection`.

Comment: I'm inclined to say it's the `t.run()` cause the tasks `t` might be changed by `run()` ...

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug! I forgot the scenario where the task ran in doTask() can actually call addTask(). However I am a bit confused why this can happen as I thought the "tasks" object would be locked by the doTask() function.

Comment: The `Thread` already has a lock so it works fine. `synchronized` prevents other `Thread`s from acquiring the monitor on `tasks` but the `Thread` in question already has the monitor.

Comment: Exactly what @BoristheSpider said. The locks are [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex), so if the thread tried to obtain the lock a second time, it would be granted. Ergo, Trinimon's answer was correct.

Comment: If they weren't reentrant, your thread would have deadlocked itself! Think about it: it would block on trying to add a task, and it wouldn't be able to unblock until it completed the doTask that's blocked by the attempt to add. It's like stopping your car at a stop sign and not starting it back up again until you're home.