# Why am I getting a concurrent modification error?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, lwjgl

I have a synchronized method called getChunks().  This is the only way the set of chunks are called in the whole program, yet when iterating through them (by calling getChunks()) I get a concurrentModificationException.  This would be because the ChunkManager class, which runs in a seperate thread, would have generated a new chunk.  But the only way it accesses the chunks is though getChunks()...

The getChunks() method:

```
public synchronized Set<WorldChunk> getChunks() {
    return chunks;
}
```

The render() method, where the exception occurs

```
public void render() {
    for(WorldChunk wc : chunkMap.getChunks()) { // <-- This is the line where the exception occurs
        wc.render();
    }
}
```

The ChunkManager Class

```
public class ChunkManager implements Runnable {

    private static final int CHUNK_UPDATE_DELAY_MILLIS = 100;

    private ChunkMap chunkMap;

    public ChunkManager(ChunkMap chunkMap) {
        this.chunkMap = chunkMap;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            manageChunks();
        }
    }

    private void manageChunks() {
        int cx = (int) ((Camera.getX() + WorldChunk.CHUNK_WIDTH / 2) / WorldChunk.CHUNK_WIDTH);
        int cz = (int) ((Camera.getZ() + WorldChunk.CHUNK_DEPTH / 2) / WorldChunk.CHUNK_DEPTH);
        int renderDistance = 2;
        for(int icx = cx - renderDistance; icx < cx + renderDistance; icx++) {
            for(int icz = cz - renderDistance; icz < cz + renderDistance; icz++) {
                if(!chunkMap.hasChunk(icx, icz)) {
                    chunkMap.genChunk(icx, icz, false);
                }
            }
        }
        for(WorldChunk wc : chunkMap.getChunks()) {
            if((Math.abs(wc.getX() - Camera.getX()) + Math.abs(wc.getZ() - Camera.getZ())) > WorldChunk.CHUNK_WIDTH + WorldChunk.CHUNK_DEPTH)  {
                wc.unload();
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(CHUNK_UPDATE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

EDIT
StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:894)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:928)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:333)
at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:117)
at com.ryxuma.kalidus.world.World.render(World.java:35)
at com.ryxuma.kalidus.Core.renderPerspective(Core.java:35)
at org.heatstroke.Heatstroke$Runner.run(Heatstroke.java:365)
at org.heatstroke.Heatstroke.start(Heatstroke.java:124)
at com.ryxuma.kalidus.Core.main(Core.java:60)
```

Comment: Some thread updates chunks while you're in method render, you can avoid it by synchronizing around `chunkMap`

Comment: @MarekSebera But I thought by synchronizing the getChunks() method, the thread that updates the chunks would wait for the iteration to finish before chaning it

Comment: Any stacktrace you can post? Which line throws the exception?

Comment: @Ryxuma: No; it just waits for that method to return.  It doesn't have anything to do with the object it returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException despite using synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-despite-using-synchronized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `wc.unload()` method do?

If you try to add/remove elements from a `Set` while you are iterating on it, you can receive this error.

Look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html

Specially this part:

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. **For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.**

For a solution, the easiest I can think of, keep track of all the elements you want to remove and remove them after you are done iterating by using `Set.removeAll()`.

If you want, take a look at `java.util.concurrent` where you can find collections that allow  you to modify as you iterate (keep an eye for how they work though, as that can be not what you expect).

Comment: removes it from the hash map.  But it is called synchronizingly(?) so it wouldn't matter?

Comment: Yes, it matters. The problem is not modifying the data from different threads, but modifying the data as you iterate over it.

Comment: what would you suggest then? :/

Comment: Added the suggestion to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your operation to get a reference to the set is thread safe, but nothing you do with that set is thread safe from that point.  A simple solution is to either

- return a copy of the set
- lock the set while iterating
- use a set which doesn't throw CME like CopyOnWriteArraySet 
  (Which can be more expensive when you update it)

---

EDIT: For those interested, if you want a ConcurrentHashSet there is a trick you can use

```
Set <E> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>());
```

Comment: When I try to make a copy I get a error because it's changed when I iterate over it to make a new one.

Comment: @Ryxuma This means its is being changed without being locked first.

Comment: Thanks! Although I got it sorted by using a ConcurrentHashMap :)

Comment: @Ryxuma if you want a ConcurrentHashSet there is a trick you can use `Set <E> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<E, Boolean>());`