# Why is there a ConcurrentModificationException even when list is synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I have Android multi-threading application.

There is some probability that two or more triggers might run the same part of code.

I have a list of objects.

I made it to be synchronized by `Collections.synchronizedList`

```
private List<WmGroupItemSample> mGroupItemSampleList;

mGroupItemSampleList = new ArrayList<WmGroupItemSample>();
mGroupItemSampleList = Collections.synchronizedList(mGroupItemSampleList);
```

However **sometimes** I get Exception on line:

```
Collections.sort(mGroupItemSampleList, new GroupItemSampleComparator());
```

---

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
       at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:62)
       at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:1895)
```

- Is this flow legal?
- do I need create the copy and run sort on copy?
- why `Collections.synchronizedList` doesn't prevent this Exception?

**[EDIT]**

*GroupItemSampleComparator*

```
public class GroupItemSampleComparator implements java.util.Comparator<WmGroupItemSample> {

    public GroupItemSampleComparator() {
        super();        
    }

    public int compare(WmGroupItemSample s1, WmGroupItemSample s2) {
       return ( (s2.getStartDate() - s1.getStartDate()) > 0 ) ? (-1) : (1);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: This exception can be reproduced *without* any [additional] threads - thus, synchronization has no bearing.

Comment: @user2864740 how can I solve this issue so? thanks

Comment: So why did you synchronize it in the first place? The answer lies in the comparator. So some code would be helpful.

Comment: @Scheintod added Comparator class

Comment: Instead of iterating over the list, give the simple for loop a try:

`for (int i = 0; i < yourList.size(); i++) {
    Object obj = yourList.get(i);
    // Do something woth your object
}`

Comment: FYI: Your `Comparator` does not consider equal start dates (that might turn out to be a problem).

Comment: Doesn't seem to be so clear now :) but try rewriting it as return s1.getStartDate() - s2.getStartDate()

Comment: Which Java version are you using? I've looked at some Collections.java, but line 1895 isn't anywhere near sort.

Comment: Guys, why are you focusing on the comparator?

Comment: Is you application multithreaded or not, i.e., can you exclude that any other thread accesses the List during the sort?

Comment: @laune I use Java 1.6

Comment: @Scheintod It would result in compilation error if `getStartDate() returns `long`.

Comment: @laune I have Android multi-threading application.

There is some probability that two or more triggers might run the same part of code.

Comment: @icza. You're right. So instead see your answer :)

Comment: @PavelHoral: Because there is nothing else to focus on. If it's ConcurrentModificationException then there has to be a concurrent modification. We're trying to find it.

Comment: Fessy already provided answer to his own question in the last comment. If he calls `Collections.sort` concurrently, it will result in `ConcurrentModificationException`. Sorting obviously uses iterators (see stack trace) to go through the collection. There is nothing special about the comparator. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#177

Comment: @pavel: i remember reading the original question as if this happened without multiple threads. This is why everyone asks for the comparator. Reading the edited version it seems as if this is just "normal" concurrent modification.

Comment: So I think launes answer is the correct one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException despite using synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-despite-using-synchronized)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The basic problem is that a synchronized list is not synchronized in a useful way.

The problem is that while its methods are synchronized, actions like moving elements that should be atomic are not, because the separate calls needed for the move are not synchronized *together*. It means other threads can get in between individual method calls. Thus synchronized collections are largely deprecated now.

Despite this flaw, if you have another thread add an element while your thread is sorting, you'll get this exception because sort iterates and changing the list during iteration causes the exception.

Fortunately, the JDK has new Collection classes that have industrial strength (and useful) synchronization, courtesy of the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Replace your list with a [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), don't "synchronize" it and you'll be good to go.

Comment: you know that in this case I can't use `Collections.sort`

Comment: it works but the problem is that "The iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created"

Comment: "separate calls needed for the move are not synchronized together" - You can synchronize multiple method calls together by calling them within a block synchronized on the list directly. The following code sorts the list while forcing other threads to wait until the sort is finished before modifying the list: `synchronized (mGroupItemSampleList) { Collections.sort(mGroupItemSampleList, new GroupItemSampleComparator()); }`

Comment: @Jack but that’s exactly the *problem*. If you have a “synchronised list” you don’t expect to have to synchronise it yourself! So people don’t, and there are inevitable errors.

Comment: @Bohemian Agreed, I merely wanted to mention that it's _possible_ to perform multiple operations on a synchronized list atomically. The answer as written suggests it's not possible and that the only recourse is to use a different implementation.

Answer (score 9):

`Collections.synchronizedList(list)` returns a synchronized list which means that the methods of the list will be synchronizd (only one of them can be running at the same time).

This however **does not** mean you can't call a method of the list while someone else (or maybe you) is iterating over the list using its iterator (iterators returned by `iterator()` are not synchronized). `synchronizedList()` does not protect you from getting a `ConcurrentModificationException` if someone is iterating over the list and it is modified in any other way than the iterator's methods.

**Edit:**

Also your `GroupItemSampleComparator` is bad, it must return `0` if the passed 2 objects are considered to be equal by their `equals()` method. Try this (assuming `getStartDate()` returns `long`):

```
public int compare(WmGroupItemSample s1, WmGroupItemSample s2) {
    long diff = s2.getStartDate() - s1.getStartDate();
    return diff > 0 ? -1 : diff < 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps - not seeing all of the code and with the chance of other accesses to the list. Quoting from  Javadoc on `synchronizedList(List<T> list)`

Returns a synchronized (thread-safe) list backed by the specified list. In order to guarantee serial access, it is critical that all access to the backing list is accomplished through the returned list.

It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
  ...
synchronized (list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

*So, are all iterations over this list guarded in this way?*

Answer (score 2):

This exception does not occur only in multithreaded environments. For example, if you're iterating over a list and removing an element during an iteration, this exception can occur (depending on the way you're removing that element).

Comment: I know that but why Exception points me to `Collections.sort`? I can understand that sort process removes and appends items for sort goal. How can I get rid of that?

Comment: @fessy Could you provide your `GroupItemSampleComparator`?

Comment: added GroupItemSampleComparator class