# Java - ConcurrentModificationException in multithreaded program, Set is wrapped with synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a crash in the following code:

```
private LocalBundle(Bundle b, Map<Bundle, LocalBundle> clonnedObjs) {
    this();
    synchronized (b.getVariables()) { // b.getVariables() is Set
        addFrom(b, clonnedObjs);
    }
}
```

but in addFrom I get the crash:

```
private synchronized void addFrom(Bundle b, Map<Bundle, LocalBundle> clonnedObjs) {
    Set<TaintedVariable> variablesOfBundle = b.getVariables();
    for(TaintedVariable v : variablesOfBundle) {
```

Exception message:

```
Exception in thread "pool-4-thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at x.y.z.LocalBundle.addFrom(VisitedNodesWithBundle.java:198)
```

Does someone know why it happens? I wrapped with `synchronized (b.getVariables())`, but it looks like that two threads are executing `for(TaintedVariable v : variablesOfBundle)`

Comment: Please show the code inside the enhanced for loop.

Comment: "it looks like that two threads are executing" Not necessarily. You can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` with a single thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcurrentModificationException despite using synchronized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655362/concurrentmodificationexception-despite-using-synchronized)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to remember about `synchronized` is that it only guarantees exclusive access if everybody accessing the shared resource also synchronizes.

For example, you can synchronize access to a shared variable:

```
synchronized (foo) {
  foo.setBar();
}
```

And you can *think* that you have exclusive access to it. However, there is nothing to stop another thread just doing something without the `synchronized` block:

```
foo.setBar();  // No synchronization first.
```

From your description, it sounds like this is happening; you've not given any details of what the "rogue" thread is doing, though.

If it is simply adding elements to the set, you can make your set synchronized when you create it:

```
Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<TaintedVariable>());
```

Now individual calls to methods on the set will be synchronized, and so you would no longer get a CME. Note, however, that the synchronization is applied *per method call*: if you make a sequence of calls (e.g. if set contains `foo` then add `bar`), you need an explicit `synchronized` block around that logic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, that the reason is another thread. Take a closer look at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) for this exception. It's said that:

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

That means, that you may cause such exception in a single thread if you try to modify the collection while you are iterating over it.

You have to check out, whether your code tries to modify the `variablesOfBundle` collection in this for-loop

```
for(TaintedVariable v : variablesOfBundle)
```

Comment: It's not necessarily in that loop; that's just where I'd suspect it is. For instance, there could be another thread in the code which modifies `b.getVariables()` without first attempting to synchronize on it.

Comment: @AndyTurner, looks like you're right. It's modified in another thread, but by another code in another class (since inside the loop is no any modification of `variablesOfBundle`)